# In what directory / folder do you install Rails Scaffold

Tags: ruby-on-rails, directory, scaffolding

I am following the Rails Tutorial.  It is starting to generate a scaffold.  I just don't know for sure where to pit it.  In a subdirectory or right at the root.  My hunch is the root. i.e. JimJones$ not JimJones$/work/newapp.  The apps can keep[ changing so I would imagine I would install the scaffold at the root.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks, Chris

Comment: Go to your newly created rails application directory and run scaffold. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your hunch is wrong, you should be in your `/newapp` directory, assuming that's the name of your app.

If you're not sure where you're at, enter `pwd` at the command line, and this will 
print out your current location. If it ends in `/newapp`, you're all good.

`rails generate scaffold myscaffold` creates a set of MVC scaffolds called `myscaffold(s)`, INSIDE your current app. In fact, You shouldn't be able to run `rails generate scaffold` unless you are inside a rails project.

Answer (score 0):

Scaffolding is specific to `Rails` applications. First create a new `Rails` application using `rails new appname` command. Then move to the `appname` directory.

Then use scaffolding

```
rails generate scaffold test
```

The above command will generate a set of model, database migration for that model, controller, views, and test suites for the resource `test`

More info on scaffolding : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html

Answer (score 0):

You need to be in the rails app directory to use scaffold and the code generated by scaffold will be put in appropriate locations in your rails app directory e.g. model in models directory controller in controllers